# Right adjoints to forgetful functors from TopRing and TopGrp to Top

Tags: category-theory, topological-groups, adjoint-functors, topological-rings

I believe the forgetful functor $F: \mathbf{TopGrp} \to \mathbf{Top}$ has a left adjoint. Does it also have a right adjoint? Does the forgetful functor $G: \mathbf{TopRing} \to \mathbf{Top}$ have a right adjoint? A reference would be very much appreciated.

Comment: To have a right adjoint, a functor must preserve colimits. Do these functors preserve colimits?

Comment: Also, the forgetful functors from $\mathbf{TopGrp} \to \mathbf{Top}$ (resp. $\mathbf{TopRing} \to \mathbf{Top}$, etc) will have left adjoints. In fact, forgetful functors from algebraic gadgets over $\mathbf{Top}$ "tend to have" left adjoints. See, for instance, Tholen's _On Wyler's Taut Lift Theorem_, which gives general criteria under which a left adjoint from $\mathbf{Set}$ lifts to a left adjoint from $\mathbf{Top}$.

Comment: TopGrp->Top has a left adjoint: the free topological group over a space. A good reference is Chapter 7 of Topological Groups and Related Structures by Arhangel'skii and Tkachenko

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful comments!